# how do I prevent scrolling on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hi guys I want my webpage to display my registration page in full without scrolling up and down when fill the form. And I don't know how to go about it, can someone help me?

Comment: Hi! To make an answer possible, please include an example, and check the **[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** guide.

Comment: but if the form takes up more than my screen how will i see it all?

Comment: What about mobile devices?

Comment: Please don't muck with scrolling. If the page is scrolling it's because some of it is not on-screen. Disabling scrolling doesn't fix that.

Comment: So how do I fix it, because hidden it is not fixing it

Comment: @DanielChuks Make the stuff on the page smaller so it fits?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css and the overflow property. just set it on the body tag

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

you might then want to make just the form container scrollable, to allow the user fill it out even when the form does not fit perfectly within the body.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `overflow` css property to be `hidden` on both your `<body>` and `<html>` tags.

```
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In case you want to disable scrolling on mobile devices as well, set it up like this:

```
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

That will prevent scrolling on browsers and mobile devices.